# c# address lookup in osm.pbf

Tags: c#, sql-server, lucene, openstreetmap

I am trying to develop an address lookup API (possibly in Json format) from an Openstreetmap extract for my current project. My preferred language is C#.

If anyone can explain me the data/node relationship of osm.pbf extract. I have read the wiki but was unable to figure out the relationship or structure therefore couldn't do much with omssharp either.

So if someone could explain me or give me an example in any language (i just need to understand the logic/relation) how I can search/query based on building name/address string/postcode and get relevant rows in return. As google address lookup works you type an address and it gives you suggestion.

If someone can help me to figure out the data relation, I would prefer any indexing method such as lucene for faster query rather than putting load on SQL Server.

Also, if possible, a logic to find out the driving distance/route between two addresses would be excellent.

FYI: I am using great_britain.osm.pbf (985mb compressed), I have full access to Ubuntu server, can install pgSql. Tried importing in SQL server Express from a workstation with 24gb Memory, 2x6 core 2.9ghz cpu and 1tb SSD but it gives out of memory exception using osm2sql.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This link (https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/loading-open-street-map-data-in-sql-server-part-ii-ways/) can give a good idea about the relations in osm xml/pbf. If anyone was looking for it there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw OSM data is only of limited use for geocoding. You will have to preprocess this data first.

The reason is that [addresses in OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:addr) don't have to be specified in full format. For example with the widely used [Karlsruhe Schema](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/House_numbers/Karlsruhe_Schema) it is sufficient to specify the house number and street name to define a single address. Other information such as city, postcode and country can be left empty. This approach works because in OSM there are separate [administrative boundaries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative) for defining municipalities, counties, countries and so on.

Most [OSM-based geocoders](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) perform a precalculation step while importing OSM data into their database. This step calculates full address hierarchies by comparing individual address tags against the administrative boundaries they are contained in.

Don't reinvent the wheel. Creating a good geocoder is really hard. Use one of the existing OSM-based geocoders instead.

Comment: Hi scai, thanks for your quick response and I am extremely grateful because it actually gave me some clue about what to do. I had a glance at your recommendations and found some more interesting stuff such as [Photon](https://github.com/komoot/photon) (which is kind of what I was looking for). I will do some more research before I jump into anything and hopefully I will share my findings. In the meantime I have a few other things to do so it might take a while before i reply. I extremely appreciate your help. Thanks a lot mate

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept my answer if you are satisfied with it :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Another thing just wanted to share just in case anyone else is interested which is install nominatim locally if possible and if you are gonna put heavy load otherwise you can use their api to retrieve same data but fair usage policy applies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I created a SQL query that can do that for you:

https://github.com/francesco1119/OSM_to_MSSQL

you can also use it in a stored procedure and refresh your data every day.